# Line Under QED Symbol

Tags: formatting

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,graphicx}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{example}{Example}
\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{lemma}{Lemma}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$ \\ \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}{\textbf{[Problem 1]}}
\noindent \\ \noindent
Proof here.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

At the end of a proof, I want there to be a line that spans the width of the page (so, when a QED symbol is place, about 0.2cm below it I want there to be a long underline that goes left to right). What code is necessary for this? I tried using

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$ \\ \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}
```

But it did not give what I wanted at all.

EDIT: Made code compilable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,graphicx}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{example}{Example}
\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{lemma}{Lemma}
\let\oldendproof\endproof
\renewcommand{\endproof}{\vspace*{-0.4cm}\oldendproof\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}{\textbf{[Problem 1]}}
\noindent \\ \noindent
Proof here.
\end{proof}
Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is good. I was wondering if we could control how close the line is to the square, though? (For example, could we make distance from the bottom of the square to the line 0.2 inch, 0.3 inch, etc?

Comment: @Primes Sure, I updated my answer.